# Extracting JSON data from column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

If we have a pandas dataframe df1 with a column `Car_Info`.

How do we extract the information in the following strings into new columns? i.e. using regex vs. pd.read_json()?

Please note the formatting for "`car_id`" and "`wheel_id`" are slightly different than the formatting for "`price`" and "`count_results`".

```
Car_Info

'{"car_id":"100","wheel_id":"80-ABC-999","price":14,"count_results":1051}'
'{"car_id":"200","wheel_id":"90-XY-6134","price":245,"count_results":37}'
'{"car_id":"300","wheel_id":"100-QRST-83751","price":729,"count_results":203}'
```

More specifically, how do we manipulate the Car_Info column to add the following four columns to the pandas dataframe df1?

```
car_id
        100 
        200
        300

wheel_id
        80-ABC-999
        90-XY-6134
        100-QRST-83751

price
        14
        245
        729


count_results
        1051
        37
        203
```

Comment: Your input is JSON. Please tag [json]. There are many duplicates on reading JSON into pandas.

Comment: How can you convert the JSON column to a dictionary and extract the results for car_id, wheel_id, price and count_results?

Comment: I see you crossposted this 2 hours later as [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066019/using-regex-to-extract-information-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066019/using-regex-to-extract-information-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column), this is frowned upon. Also you didn't phrase it as "Parse JSON into pandas using regex".

Answer (score 0):

This is JSON, and pandas can directly import JSON:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_json('{"car_id":"100","wheel_id":"80-ABC-999","price":14,"count_results":1051}', lines=True)

   car_id  count_results  price    wheel_id
0     100           1051     14  80-ABC-999
```

Comment: How would you answer this question using regex?

Comment: @user9723782: Don't. Don't rewrite libraries. Don't reinvent the wheel, even if you could duplicate the tens of thousands of man-hours that went into pandas. I see you crossposted this as [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066019/using-regex-to-extract-information-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066019/using-regex-to-extract-information-from-a-pandas-dataframe-column), this is frowned upon on SO. Also you didn't phrase it as "Parse JSON into pandas using regex".

Answer (score -1):

Below I have created code that creates a new dataframe that solves your issue. This data frame can be merged back onto your original dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for row in range(len(df1['car'])):
     df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(df1['car_info'][row])]))
```

The function literal_eval can be imported from ast to handle the strings in the column as dictionaries.

Comment: How would you answer this question using regex?